# New Backbone instance property pointing to old instance property

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I noticed something odd with Backbone/Marionette. When I create an instance of a view that has a new collection property, then I create a nother instance of the view, its a new instance but the collection property points to the instance of the first view. See here:

```
  var CollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    collection: new Backbone.Collection() 
  });

  var view = new CollectionView();

  console.log('view is ', view);
  view.collection.searchTerm = 'test';
  console.log('view.collection is ', view.collection);

  this.region.show(view);

  var view2 = new CollectionView();
  console.log('view2 is ', view2);
  console.log('view2.collection is ', view2.collection);

  this.region.show(view2);
```

You can see in the logs, there are 2 difference view instances (one has cid: "view2" and the other cid: "view5"). But the collection property of the second view has a property `searchTerm` which is 'test'. I would have expected this to be a new Backbone collection....

Codepen is [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ObLJoQ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is expected behavior.

Collection is created only once, when you're calling `extend`. All instances just have `collection` reference in prototype of `CollectionView`.

If you want your view instantiated with new collection every time, just create `initialize` method:

```
var CollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.collection = new Backbone.Collection();
    }
});

var view = new CollectionView();

console.log('view is ', view);
view.collection.searchTerm = 'test';
console.log('view.collection is ', view.collection);

this.region.show(view);

var view2 = new CollectionView();
console.log('view2 is ', view2);
console.log('view2.collection is ', view2.collection);

this.region.show(view2);
```